# Detect blurred image

Tags: iphone, image, camera, blur

When the camera is on, how can I know when the image is not blurred because of the camera motion ? The iPhone is doing some image processing to remove blur effect, so I want to take a picture when the image is actually net and not before the iPhone image processing.